# Abstract Algebra - Cyclic Subgroups with a Proper Subgroup of Infinite Order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a cyclic subgroup has a proper subgroup of infinite order, how many finite subgroups does it have?  Explain.  Any help appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Cyclic subgroup in *what* exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to see that a cyclic infinite group is isomorphic to the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$: being cyclic, it is generated my one element, $x$ say, and being infinite, no power of $x$ is equal to the identity. Consequently it is formed by the integer powers of $x$, and not two of them are equal.

The answer to your question consequently is that an infinite cyclic group cannot have a nontrivial finite subgroup.